# What happens if an AP rejects an Association Request from an STA?

Tags: wifi

In the 802.11 association process an STA will send an `Association Request` to the AP which it has discovered to have the highest `RSSI` (Received Signal Strength Indicator). If the AP responds with an `Association Response`, then the STA-AP association is complete. But what if there is no response from the selected AP? Would the STA move on to try to associate with the AP with the next highest RSSI? Or else would it simple retry to connect to the initial AP (which has the highest RSSI)?

Answer (score 0):

This would be an unacknowledged frame and the client will retransmit the frame. A normally functioning access point (AP) will send a frame ACK and then respond with either a status code of success or error.